# Pythonのモジュールを使って日付を整形

Tags: python, python3

SQLデータベースから取得したデータをpythonで整形したいのですか、
この場合、モジュールを使って日付をシンプルにできたりしないでしょうか？
また2.26を四捨五入して2.3％と表記させたいです。

整形前
`[(datetime.date(2016, 7, 17), 2.26268624680273)]`

整形後
`July 17, 2016 — 2.3% errors`

Comment: 前回と同様に `print '\n'.join([u'%s — %.1f%% errors' % (t.strftime('%b %d, %Y'), v) for (t, v) in lst])` など。

Comment: results = (datetime.date(2016, 7, 17), 2.26268624680273)
    for e in results:
        date=(e[0])
        per_err=(e[1])
        print (date.strftime('%B %d, %Y') + '--' + round(per_err,1))

Comment: +を使って繋ごうとすると、下記のエラーになるんですが、何故でしょうか？  　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　    print (date.strftime('%B %d, %Y') + '--' + round(per_err,1))
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly

Comment: エラーメッセージに書いてある通り、float と文字列は結合できないので、`str(round(per_err, 1))` とするなど。ところで、python2 ではなく python3 を使っているのですか？

Comment: 数値を文字列に変換して繋げばいいんですね。　はい、python3使ってます。

Comment: タグ(`python3`)を追加しました。

Answer (score 1):

Python3 をお使いということなので，format メソッドを用いるのが一番自然だと思います．

f オプションを使用すると，小数点以下の桁数も簡単に指定することができます．

```
ls = [(datetime.date(2016, 7, 17), 2.26268624680273)]
for t, v in ls:
    print("{} - {:.1f}% errors".format(t.strftime("%B %d, %Y"), v))
```

参考：http://uxmilk.jp/40547

Comment: formatメソッドが一番コードも見やすく分かりやすくていいですね。stringにして無理やり+で繋いでいたんですが、参考のformatメソッドのサイトも分かりやすく参考になります。